# S3 served images are fine... then become blocked due to expiring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can upload images, folders etc remotely.  But when serving the images on my website I find they work temporarily and then disappear.

Here are my bucket permissions:

```
`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1580055036544",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1580055031619",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::240479180938:user/**************"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::******-images/*"
        }
    ]
}`
```

I've starred out the names deliberately.

My bucket states that it's publicly accessibible, so I'm guessing files are signed and expire at some point.

I have also tried changing it to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here you can see it is a publicly accessible bucket, but the images are signed for 1 hour I believe.

[image: My S3]

I also changed the ACL in this other section but that also didn't help.

[image: Access control list (ACL) S3 Bucket]

I have no idea why my links are expiring but I'm sure it's a simple setting somewhere.

Comment: you should use a cdn for a long lived image url

Comment: It is possible that you are using [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3. Please show us a URL that your app is using to display the image and we can tell you if this is the situation.

Comment: The first code sample would only provide access to the bucket for the stated User, and they would need to provide AWS credentials to authenticate to S3. The second code sample makes the entire bucket 'public'.

Comment: Here's an example URL: https://s3.dualstack.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/squareballoon-co-uk--media/blogs/excel-dropdowns/how-to-add-dropdowns-in-excel--intro.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATP7NNDCFNHMPR5NM%2F20240222%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240222T174640Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=9b0d49515468c4771f8bf311722c58942a33bc2de31552db7111bf55e9148ad7#joomlaImage://s3-S3/blogs/excel-dropdowns/how-to-add-dropdowns-in-excel--intro.png?width=446&height=446

Comment: I will use a CDN, but I wanted to get it working first, thus I tried to reduce the number of variables.  Surely there must be a way to do an image that doesn't expire?

Comment: For reference I am not using the URLs directly, I am using a plugin for Joomla.  The developer is very experienced and I know others that are using the plugin, so it must be my configuration that is different.